# C# compiler, Calling a valid constructor gives error

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

[image]

Well , the picture speaks for itself.

- Silverlight project
- VS 2015 ( tried also with 2013 and 2012 )

Comment: Are you sure  you reference the latest source code? I had such problems when I was referencing a `*.dll` file instead of a VS project file

Comment: I opened this project after long time (which means no problem before).... tried diffrent VS versions

Comment: Are `Log.cs` file and `StackFrame` class part of the same VS project?

Comment: yes , StackFrame is part of  System.Diagnostics

Comment: I think [Select isn't broken](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) applies. Trying different VS versions merely *decreases* the possibility of this being a compiler bug

Comment: Please provide an actual, compilable example. I can't reproduce what you describe with a single line in LinqPad 4, LinqPad 5, and I bet I won't be able to reproduce it with a console application targetting various framework and language versions either.

Comment: can you make a new silverlight project and copy this      var xx = new StackFrame(2, false); ?

Comment: Indeed, [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/deysbxxw(v=vs.95).aspx) is supported in Silverlight 3 and 4, not 5 or Phone 8+. Which is why the compiler throws an error. The question is, where does the metadata screenshot come from?

Comment: from F12 on the class , #region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v5.0.5.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\mscorlib.dll
#endregion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a documented restriction, the constructor you are trying to use is not supported in Silverlight version 5.  From the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deysbxxw%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Supported in: 4, 3

Not crystal why it was dropped, probably has something to do with it being [SecurityCritical].

Why your IntelliSense still shows it is hard to guess, I certainly can't repro that.  You probably ought to verify the path to the mscorlib reference, mine points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\mscorlib.dll